# In Ansible loop, test existence of files from registered results

Tags: ansible

I have several files that I need to backup in different directories.  I have tried the code below and not working for me.

```
  vars:
    file_vars:
      - {name: /file1}
      - {name: /etc/file2}
      - {name: /etc/file/file3}

  tasks:

  - name: "Checking if config files exists"
    stat:
      path: "{{ item.name }}"
    with_items: "{{ file_vars }}"
    register: stat_result

  - name: Backup Files
    copy: src={{ item.name }} dest={{ item.name }}{{ ansible_date_time.date }}.bak
    with_items: "{{ file_vars }}"
    remote_src: yes
    when: stat_result.stat.exists == True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try using below worked for me:

```
---
- name: Copy files
  hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  vars_files:
    - files.yml


  tasks:

  - name: "Checking if config files exists"
    stat:
    path: "{{ item }}"
    with_items: "{{ files }}"
    register: stat_result

  - name: Ansible
    debug:
      msg: "{{ stat_result }}"

  - name: Backup Files
    copy:
      src: "{{ item }}"
      dest: "{{ item.bak }}"
    with_items: "{{ files }}"
    when: stat_result == "True"
```

and files.yml will look like:

```
---
files:
   - /tmp/file1
   - /tmp/file2
```

you can check you playbook syntax using below command:
    ansible-playbook copy.yml --syntax-check

Also you do dry run your playbook before actual execution.
    ansible-playbook -i localhost copy.yml --check

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the condition

```
when: stat_result.stat.exists == True
```

There is no attribute `stat_result.stat`. Instead, the attribute `stat_result.results` is a list of the results from the loop. It's possible to create a dictionary of files and their statuses. For example

```
   - set_fact:
        files_stats: "{{ dict(my_files|zip(my_stats)) }}"
      vars:
        my_files: "{{ stat_result.results|json_query('[].item.name') }}"
        my_stats: "{{ stat_result.results|json_query('[].stat.exists') }}"
```

Then simply use this dictionary in the condition

```
when: files_stats[item.name]
```

---

Below is a shorter version which creates the dictionary more efficiently

```
   - set_fact:
       files_stats: "{{ dict(stat_result.results|
                        json_query('[].[item.name, stat.exists]')) }}"
```